# How to install expo .ipa on iPhone 6?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I have build an ipa with `expo build:ios --apple-id ${EXPO_APPLE_ID} -t simulator --release-channel staging --non-interactive`.

I have downloaded the ipa using `curl -o ${CI_BUILD_TAG}-staging.ipa "$(npx expo url:ipa --non-interactive)"` and I want to install it with XCode on an iPhone 6.

Within xcode, I go on `Window > Devices and Simulator`, on the left panel I see my iPhone, where I can drag and drop `.ipa` into `Installed Apps` list.

I expect the ipa to install, instead I have the following error:

[image]

I have never published on the app store and this is my first native app.

Is it Xcode or the ipa, is there a way to solve this?

Does that mean my app is broken and won't work on iOS because locally it works and I do not want to be fooled?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a certificate and provisional profile and add your device id in the device list at apple developer.

[Apple certificate and provisional Docs](https://appaloosa-store.readme.io/docs/getting-started-with-apple-certificates)

then add certificates and provisional profiles in the expo.

[Expo App Signing Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/app-signing/)

then create an expo release build

[Expo create build docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/)

then upload build to
[Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) or [installonair](https://www.installonair.com/) so they will give a download URL and open that URL on your device and install the app.

Comment: I do not have an apple developer account, can I install the tar.gz/ipa without it?

Comment: without a developer account, you can't install IPA in a device. there is only one way to install an app on a device without a developer account. and it is install an app through Xcode.

Comment: I think first you need to eject expo project, then you find an iOS folder and open xcodeProj file through Xcode and make free developer account and add in Xcode then install an app in device from Xcode.

Comment: My generated .ipa has 224MB, and the free account to use in Diawi is 50MB. With InstallOnAir, after a long time trying to install I receive the error: "Unable To Install ... Please try again later."